# WPBakery (Visual Composer) Não funciona localhost

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Tenho uma instalação local do Wordpress em minha maquina, que roda através do Xampp.

Obtive um tema através do site themeforest, e com ele vem o plugin WPBakery Page Builder. 
O grande problema é que quando adiciono um elemento a alguma página, ele não me mostra o elemento no painel administrativo. No front-End ele aparece normal.
Abaixo imagem, adicionei um elemento(buttom) ele só aparece no front-end, no back-and o elemento só aparece no editor classico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o erro apresentado com uma solução até que simples, mas estou publicando aqui para ajudar alguém com o mesmo erro.

Basta atualizar a versão do PHP para 7.0.x, no meu caso utilizei PHP Version 7.0.27

Tudo funcionando perfeitamente agora.